# Convert SQL query to peewee

Tags: sql, orm, peewee, flask-peewee

I need convert a SQL query to peewee instructions.

My SQL is:

```
    parts_test = db.execute('''
    SELECT tokenID, rewardCount FROM Loot
    INNER JOIN Quests ON Loot.questID = Quests.questID
    INNER JOIN Rewards ON Loot.rewardID = Rewards.rewardID
    WHERE Quests.questID = ? AND tokenContract = ?
    ORDER BY rewardCount
    ''', (quest_id, f"{PARTS_ADDR}")
).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your column names are not following the peewee conventions, so you may need to modify, but roughly the below code should be clear enough to give you what you need:

```
(Loot
 .select(Loot.token_id, Loot.reward_count)
 .join_from(Loot, Quests, on=(Loot.quest == Quest.id))
 .join_from(Loot, Rewards, on=(Loot.reward == Reward.id))
 .where((Quest.id == quest_id) & (Loot.token_contract == X))
 .order_by(Loot.reward_count))
```